# How to filter data in laravel by relationship of parent object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I've got 3 models: `Client`,  `Organization` nad `Industry`. I want to filter and display clients, that are assigned to any organization in choosen Industry. 
Relations:

```
Client N-N Organization N-N Industry
```

One client can have multiple organizations and one organization can have multiple industries. I use form with `GET` method.

My controller:

```
class ClientListsController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
      $clients = new Client;
      $queries = array();
      $columns = ['statuses'];

      foreach ($columns as $column) {
        if (request()->has($column)) {

          if ($column == 'industries') {
            // filter by industries
          }

          if ($column == 'statuses' && request($column) == 1 ) {
            $clients = optional($clients->has('organizations'))->paginate(100, ['*'], 'client_page');
          }else if($column == 'statuses' && request($column) == null ){
            $clients = Client::paginate(100, ['*'], 'client_page');
          }
          else{
            $clients = $clients->whereDoesntHave('organizations')->paginate(100, ['*'], 'client_page');
          }

          $queries[$column] = request($column);

        }else{
          $clients = Client::paginate(100, ['*'], 'client_page');
        }
      }

      $organizations = Organization::paginate(100, ['*'], 'org_page');
      return view('clientLists.index')->with(['clients' => $clients, 'organizations' => $organizations]);
  }
}
```

I've tried multiple things, such as looping through current result with organizations, but that returned true or false whe using has(). 
I've also tried using `$clients = Client::all()` but my point is to paginate it further so I've worked with `Client::where('id', '*')` so I didn't get collection, but that caused, that `statuses` filter does not work.

I'm working with Laravel 6. Do you have any idea how to make universal filtering with pagination? Thanks a lot!

EDIT
relevant relationship in details (f.e. pivot table for Client - Organization is `client_organization`) with foreign keys defined.

```
App\Client
    public function Organizations()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Organization')->withTimestamps();
    }
App\Organization
  public function Clients()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client')->withTimestamps();
  }
  public function Industries()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Industry')->withTimestamps();
  }
App\Industry
  public function Organizations()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Organization')->withTimestamps();
  }
```

EDIT 2:
I'm trying to achieve my goal through SQL query, but I'm stuck with `JOINS` with many-to-many relationships.

```
$clients = DB::table('clients')
->leftJoin('client_organization', 'client_organization.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')->leftJoin('industry_organization', 'industry_organization.organization_id', '=', 'organizations.id')
->whereIn('industry_organization.industry_id', request($column))
->paginate(100, ['*'], 'client_page');
}
```

```
select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  `clients`
  left join `client_organization` on `client_organization`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id`
  left join `industry_organization` on `industry_organization`.`organization_id` = `organizations`.`id`
where
  `industry_organization`.`industry_id` in (2)`
```

This query returns `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'organizations.id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Can you post your relationships please?

Comment: sure, here you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it this way:

```
      if (request()->industries[0] != "") {
        $clients = $clients->with('organizations')->whereHas('organizations', function($query){
          $query->with('industries')->whereHas('industries', function($query2){
            $query2->whereIn('industry_id', request()->industries);
          });
        });
      }
```

Thanks for your help boys :)

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have the `$industry` you can find all of the Organisations within it using your relationships:

`$organisations = $industry->organisations();`

Then, you want to get all clients for each organisation:

```
$clients = [];

foreach ($organisations as $organisation) {
    $clients[$organisation] = $orgination->clients()->toArray();
}
```

Or, alternatively, to give it a go all in one query:

```
$industries = request($column);

$clients = DB::table('clients')
    ->leftJoin('client_organization', 'client_organization.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
    ->leftJoin('organizations', 'organizations.id', '=', 'client_organization.id')
    ->leftJoin('industry_organization', 'industry_organization.organization_id', '=', 'organizations.id')
    ->whereIn('organisations.industry_id', $industries)
    ->paginate(10);
```

Try this line by line to check it out and debug it easily (try `->get()` after the first `leftJoin` and check that it works; if that's okay, try  it after the second.

Comment: That's interesting! I've tried this, but still, you can not paginate array :(

Comment: @NorbertJurga I've added a query for you, will need some tweaking depending on your database structure - I've not tried it out but if you have any questions let me know

Comment: not the case when I do have many to many relationships, as far as I can see. The other fing is that my `$_GET['industries']` is an array, so I have to be able to check for multiple industries, so I can't make a query and reset `$clients` defined before.

Comment: Well you can just use `whereIn` instead of `where` and pass in the array.

Comment: The 'all in one' query is me offering an alternative where you can use pagination instead of going through the relationships and building it up like that.

Comment: You're right :) Could you check my last edit? Thank you!

Comment: Hey @NorbertJurga - do you have a table organizations with a column id?

Comment: Yeah. I created sql-related question where you can find all Schemas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164386/laravel-left-joins-with-n-n-relationships

Comment: You haven't joined the organisations table in the query :)

Comment: You need to add the line from the answer where you left join the organisations table

Comment: yeah, we're further now, but I got result from organizations table with pivot tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200151/discussion-between-norbert-jurga-and-party-ring).

Comment: Ok, I know why. I have `name` both in `clients` and `organizations`, that is probably the confusion :)